# Login/Register with Facebook button on iOS Safari. HOw do i use Iphone Facebook app for authentication

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, registration

Problem:
1. My client has a simple website.  They use login/register with Facebook.

2. The Register/Login is not smooth on iphones.  The user is being redirected to www.facebook.com on Safari.

   - Most people are not logged into FB in Safari.
   - But most people have FB App installed and are logged in.
3. How do i redirect the auth/permissions to the Facebook App,  and avoid having the user to log into Facebook on the browser.

Thanks

Gooch

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the "Single Sign On" feature in the browser afaik. I´m afraid you will have to let users login again.